# Using regex in scraping value from json in ansible task

Tags: regex, ansible, influxdb-2

I've a task in ansible where I've to extract value of token from a json object, which is as follows:

```
{
"token.stdout_lines": [
    "{",
    "\t\"id\": \"08320829d85c7000\",",
    "\t\"description\": \"\",",
    "\t\"token\": \"zMiyCw7X6u_IjBpTbD1Nvt4eGk-dxBXWWOqRCgWh_KiYtp7AjD5mML5mBIEtApncBSXwU3QqexT_4VVmEv0WeA==\",",
    "\t\"status\": \"active\",",
    "\t\"userName\": \"telegraf\",",
    "\t\"userID\": \"0831cb0c68dc7000\",",
    "\t\"permissions\": [",
    "\t\t\"read:orgs/ea37b04111f50748/buckets\",",
    "\t\t\"write:orgs/ea37b04111f50748/buckets\"",
    "\t]",
    "}"
]
}
```

In order to retrieve the value of the token, I followed these steps:

```
- set_fact:
myvalue: "{{ token.stdout_lines | regex_search('regexp')}}"
  vars:
regexp: 'token([^"]+)":([^"]+)"([^.{\\}$"]+)'
- debug:
var: myvalue
```

The output I get is a null value in myvalue.

Can anyone point to where I am making a mistake?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if regexp is the best answer in this case.

Why not do just something like

```yaml
- set_fact:
    myvalue: "{{ token.stdout_lines | from_json }}"
- debug:
    var: myvalue.token
```

See more on [Ansible's website](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove unnecessary groups. Regex: `token[^"]+":[^"]+"([^.{\\}$"]+)`

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/laymN3/1)